# Convergence in Distribution, Argument Converging in Probability

Tags: convergence, cumulative-distribution-function

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_{n}\leq x) = P(X\leq x)$ and that $A_{n} \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} a$, where $a$ is a continuity point of $F_{X}(x) = P(X\leq x)$. Is it the case that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_{n}\leq A_{n})=P(X\leq a)$?

My approach was to bound $P(X_{n}\leq A_{n})$ as:
$P(X_{n}\leq a-\epsilon)-P(|A_{n}-a|>\epsilon) \leq P(X_{n}\leq A_{n}) \leq P(X_{n}\leq a+\epsilon) + P(|A_{n}-a|>\epsilon)$.

Taking $n\to\infty$ gives:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_{n}\leq a-\epsilon) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_{n}\leq A_{n}) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_{n}\leq a+\epsilon)$.

Taking $\epsilon\downarrow 0$ seems to give the result. Does this argument hold?

Comment: You write $A_n \to_p a$. So is $A_n$ a sequence of random variables converging in probability to a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Slutsky's theorem,

$$X_n \to_d X,\;\;\; A_n\to_p a, \;\; \implies X_n-A_n \to_d X-a$$

Then
$$\Pr(X_n \leq A_n) = \Pr(X_n - A_n\leq 0) \to \Pr(X - a\leq 0) = \Pr(X\leq a)$$

And yes, your approach is how one can prove this part of Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: Thanks, yes, Slutsky's theorem is a clear way to see this.